# Is it possible to invoke Parent class method from Child class object in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

How do I invoke a Parent class method from Child class object in Java?

From what I know, Child class object should invoke it's own implementation of any Parent class method that it has overridden, but what if I need to call the Parent's method implementation using the Child object reference? Does Java even support this?

**Sample code for explanation:**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human obj = new Aman(21);
        Aman obj2 = new Aman(21);
        System.out.println(obj.getAge()); //prints 20
        System.out.println(obj2.getAge()); //also prints 20
        System.out.println(obj.super.getAge()); //error here
        //how to invoke Human's getAge() method?
    }
}

class Human {
    int age;
    public Human(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    public String getAge() {
        return new String("Human's age is "+(this.age));
    }
}

class Aman extends Human {
    public Aman(int age) {
        super(age);
    }
    
    public String getAge() {
        return new String("Aman's age is "+(this.age-1));
    }
}
```

How do I get my code to print: "Human's age is 21"?

Comment: Your code is broken: a getter method should do just that, get a property result ***and return it***. So your `getAge()` method should simply return the age value and do nothing more. Then the calling code can print the result. Human's `getAge()` could be, `return age;` and Aman's `getAge()` could simply be: `return super.getAge() - 1;`

Comment: BTW you mostly never need to use `new String(String)` - for example, `return "Human's age is "+(this.age);` will already create the string

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for your suggestion. I made the changes as suggested by you, but sorry to say, my code still prints the same age values for both Human and Aman. Am stuck here.

Comment: @user16320675 sure. Will try to avoid `new String(String)` . Just another question, doesn't the Java Compiler internally convert all `String s = "abcd"` to `String s = "abcd".intern()` ? If yes, isn't there any performance loss with using the above syntax?

Comment: @user16320675 thanks for clarifying my doubts. I really appreciate your help. Closing this thread now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `super.getAge()` syntax is only available within subclasses. So you could do the following:

```
class Aman extends Human {
    public Aman(int age) {
        super(age);
    }
    
    public String getAge() {
        return new String("Aman's age is "+(this.age-1));
    }
    
    public String getHumanAge() {
        return super.getAge();
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that it would break encapsulation if you could just overgo the implementation of the child class by using something like `obj.super.getAge()` from outside the class of the `obj` instance.